# How to limit size of string in stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I do not see any answer on similar question regarding limiting size of read string from URL. A user can point by mistake on URL bringing several gigabytes of data which obviously will bring down my iPhone application. I want to limit size to 100Kb, is there any way to do that using the standard method?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, because the method you're referring to is pretty much a convenience method.  If you want to check the size of the request prior to making it, you might as well use `ASIHTTPRequest` or even just `NSURLConnection`.

Specifically with ASIHTTPRequest, you'll get a delegate callback when the HTTP headers are received, so you'll know the size.  Then, if the size is 100KB+, you can just cancel the request.